# Appending multiple jquery widgets to container

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-widgets

I currently am trying to append multiple widgets to a container.

```
$( "#addbutton" ).click( function() {  
    newid++;
    $("#designspace").append($("<div></div>").mywigdet({id:newid,top:100,left:100,width:100,height:100,color:"blue",text:"Hello"}));        
});
```

with this way I need to create a div and then add the widget into that div. The widget itself  does the following in the _create

```
 ...
 this._container = $('<div class="label-container" id="' + newid +'" style="position:relative; border:1px solid black;"></div>').appendTo(this.element);
 this._setOptions({
      'top': this.options.top,
      'left': this.options.left,
      'width': this.options.width,
      'height': this.options.height,
      'color': this.options.color,
      'text': this.options.text
 });
 ...
```

while it works this creates one container inside another.

But because I have relative positioning code in my widget this method prevents it from working as the blank container DIVs position is the parent.

I can move the position stuff into the container DIV but this would take away some of the flexibility of using widgets.

Is there a better way to accomplish adding multiple widgets to one container, without creating sub-containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't really played with jquery-widgets before. I think your problem is:

```
this._container = $('<div class="label-container" id="' + newid +'" style="position:relative; border:1px solid black;"></div>').appendTo(this.element);
```

Rather modify this.element itself by using:

```
$(this.element).attr('id',newid);

$(this.element).addClass('label-container');
...
```

**Edit:** I'd recommend replacing the style attribute with another css class.

[JQuery CSS](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

[JQuery addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Comment: thank you, adding and editing the original div has done the trick.